# Click in popover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I try to get `data-lang` value after `click` event on an `a` tag with this code:

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
    return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
  },
  title: function() {
    var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
    return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
  }
});

$('.popover-body').on('click', 'a', function() {
  let lang = $(this).data("lang")
  alert(lang);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="mainnav">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-popover-content="#a1">Popover</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="a1" class="hidden">
  <div class="popover-heading">_('Välj ditt språk')</div>
  <div class="popover-body">
    <div class="lang">
      <a href="#" data-lang="no">Norsk</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="de">Deutsch</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="nl">Nederlands</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="es">Español</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="dk">Dansk</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I click it, nothing happens.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because although you're using a delegated event handler, which is the correct solution to this problem, the `.popover-body` element is not cloned along with the content of the popover by the plugin. You can see this if you inspect the elements in the DOM after you open the popover.

To fix this you can use the `.mainnav` element as the primary selector of your delegated event handler:

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
    return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
  },
  title: function() {
    var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
    return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
  }
});

$('.mainnav').on('click', '.topnav div a', function() { // change this
  let lang = $(this).data("lang")
  console.log(lang);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="mainnav">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-popover-content="#a1">Popover</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="a1" class="hidden">
  <div class="popover-heading">_('Välj ditt språk')</div>
  <div class="popover-body">
    <div class="lang">
      <a href="#" data-lang="no">Norsk</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="de">Deutsch</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="nl">Nederlands</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="es">Español</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="dk">Dansk</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the selector. In the source code when the popup was open I couldn't see the class `popover-body`. This should work though:

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
    return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
  },
  title: function() {
    var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
    return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
  }
});

$('body').on('click', '.popover-content a', function() {
  let lang = $(this).data("lang")
  alert(lang);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="mainnav">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-popover-content="#a1">Popover</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="a1" class="hidden">
  <div class="popover-heading">_('Välj ditt språk')</div>
  <div class="popover-body">
    <div class="lang">
      <a href="#" data-lang="no">Norsk</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="de">Deutsch</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="nl">Nederlands</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="es">Español</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-lang="dk">Dansk</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with selector 'popover-body' which may not exist.
Take a look at JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xe54r7db/37/

```
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content"); 
      return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
    }
  });
  //Register with document parent selector to attach event.
  $(document).on('click','.popover-content a',function(e){
 // e.preventDefault();
    let lang = $(this).data("lang")
    alert(lang);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object, I change class selector to document for binding event to element

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
     let lang = $(this).data("lang")
     alert(lang);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate if you can add more details to this questions to make it useful for those who come back to this question in future